# need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, python-2.x, pycharm

Доброго времени!!! скачал недавно файлик с гитхаб [отсюда](https://github.com/illus0r/Kruglendar-2015/tree/master/py/src)...
называется календарик, который генериться с помощью питона 2хх, суть в том что автор утверждает что именно с него генерил и всё валид... но

> немного танцев с бубнами (numpy & svgfig) и как итог:
>
> /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/calendar/src/calendar.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/user/calendar/src/calendar.py", line 386, in 
>       outputFile, timeModelType, language = sys.argv[0:]
>   ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

пробовал выложить сам код, но он здесь нечитаем...

[crs + .svg](https://github.com/illus0r/Kruglendar-2015/tree/master/py/src)...

Comment: В файле по ссылке строка 386 выглядит так: `outputFile, timeModelType, language = sys.argv[1:]` (а не так как у вас в тексте ошибки). Суть ошибки в том, что в скрипт передано меньше параметров, чем он ожидает.

Comment: Скрипт в данном случае нужно вызывать как `python имя_скрипта.py имя_выходного_файла время_модель_тип язык`. (что бы это все не означало)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка 386 в исходном файле выглядит так:

```
outputFile, timeModelType, language = sys.argv[1:]
```

Суть ошибки в том, что в скрипт не передан как минимум один из параметров: имя выходного файла, модель типа времени (или тип модели времени, что бы это не означало) и язык. Вызывать скрипт нужно примерно так:

```
python calendar.py 1_параметр 2_параметр 3_параметр
```

Comment: так как вытянуть из этого файл .pdf?

Comment: @VovkaRa, открыть svg в Inkscape и сохранить в pdf. В скрипте, насколько я вижу, функционала сохранения в pdf нет.

Comment: тоесть команда должна выглядеть так? -- python calendar.py test, top ,ru... но мне после этого начинает ругаться на язык

Comment: @VovkaRa запятые не нужны

Comment: @VovkaRa, учитесь читать сообщения об ошибках: там же явно видно, что ругается на неправильный язык ',ru'. Запятая для разделения параметров в командной строке не нужна, нужен пробел.

Comment: да все есть Inkscape даже стоит уже) сори за такой вопрос, мог и сам додуматся))